# Angularjs simple grid Table sort by date

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want a button on-click I want to sort table with today date in angularjs.
If this is my **Angular view page**.

```html
 <div class="form-inline has-feedback filter-header">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" ng-model="search.$" />
      <!-- <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search form-control-feedback"></i> -->
      <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="hideFilter=!hideFilter">Advanced Search</button>
              </div>

        <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right" href="/#/add">Add New</a>
      </div> <!-- Grid filter ends -->

      <table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-responsive table-hover">
        <thead class="data-grid-header">
          <!-- table header -->
          <tr>
            <th>
              <span class="fa fa-th-large"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <a href="" ng-click="orderByField='title'; reverseSort = !reverseSort">Title</a>
            </th>
            <th class="hidden-xs">
              <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <a href="" ng-click="orderByField='startDate'; reverseSort = !reverseSort">Schedule Date</a>
            </th>
          </tr>

          <!-- table filter -->
          <tr ng-hide="hideFilter">
            <th><span ng-hide="hideFilter"><input type="text" ng-model="search.title"></span></th>
           </tr>      

        </thead>

        <tbody class="data-grid-data">
          <tr ng-repeat="visit in visitsList | filter: dateRange | filter: search |orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort">
            <td>{{visit.title}}</td>
            <td>{{visit.startDate | date:medium}}
         </tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>
```

i dont know how to fill **controller** to sort current date.
do help *thanks in advance*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function in your controller to filter the table's data for only today's date.

```
$scope.filterDates = function() {
    //Get the current date.
    var currentDate = $filter('date')(new Date(), "MM/dd/yyyy");
    $scope.users.forEach(function(user) {
        //convert dates to currentDate format for comparing.
        user.previousLogin = $filter('date')(user.previousLogin, "MM/dd/yyyy");
    });
    //filter and update users list.
    $scope.filteredUsers = $filter('filter')($scope.users, {previousLogin: currentDate});
}
```

Then call the function on `ng-click` from your button.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/npwug6xd/

Comment: yo clayton its working!!!... super thankyou..... any idea how to filter to get last week data as in filter ??

Answer (score 0):

Below code will help to sort the rows with start date in ascending order.

```
<tr ng-repeat="visit in visitsList | orderBy: 'startDate'">
    <td>{{visit.title}}</td>
    <td>{{visit.startDate | date:medium}}
</tr>
```

Comment: no i want to sort with today date example today is  3/11/2016 i want data on this date.